# How to set limitation or just notice hint for function's argument

Tags: function, go, types, arguments

how to set argument limitation like below?

// 1.

```
func ChooseColor(color string:"black|white" ) {
  fmt.Println(color)
}

ChooseColor("white") // console "white"
ChooseColor("yellow") // console panic
```

If you feel like the noob can't understand the above solution, then alternately see below

// 2.

```
/**
* arg: "black|white"
*
*/
func ChooseColor(color string) {
  fmt.Println(color)
}

ChooseColor(  ) // IDE can notice "color: black || white"
```

please help me (T.T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Go" way to do this is with godoc:

```golang
// ChooseColor selects a color. Valid colors are: black, white.
func ChooseColor(color string) {
    if color != "black" && color != "white" {
        /* handle the error condition */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

This will appear in most IDEs.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your type `Color` and have constants for this type. Something like this

```
type Color string

const (
    ColorBlack Color = "black"
    ColorWhite Color = "white"
)

func ChooseColor(color Color) {
    fmt.Println(color)
}
```

Comment: And if the type isn't exported then it's impossible for users of the package to create unintended values.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to `1.`. The function panics if given argument is not expected one.

```
func ChooseColor(color string) {
    switch color {
    case "white", "black":
        fmt.Println(color)
    default:
        panic(color)
    }
}
```

And `2.` is likely answered by Bakurits. This lets the IDE to catch what type of data will be passed to that function.

```
type Color bool

const (
    ColorBlack Color = true
    ColorWhite Color = false
)

func ChooseColor(color Color) {
    if color {
        fmt.Println("black")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("white")
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe change the type to int so as to accommodate a bigger pool?

Comment: @Kisinga Then it will allow something other than those "black" and "white" as the function's argument. Type `bool` forces the user to choose from either before runtime. I thought `1.` is asking for exception handling that happens in runtime and `2.` is more about static type checking.

Comment: Either way you can still provide true or false, as the underlying type is bool and the function is still valid. IMHO chaning it to int will only allow more colors to be defined, other than black and white, while maintaining type safety